# Remote notification sound

Tags: xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications

i would like to ask how exactly play custom sound in remote notification (I am using Xamarin Studio on mac)

My payload on website is:

```
aps = 
[
    'alert': 'MESSAGE',
    'sound': 'mario.aiff',
    'badge': 1
];
```

I put file mario.aiff into Resources folder and set Build Action to BundleResource but when i sent notification default sound is playing.

Could you please give me some advice or am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you read the documentation from Apple on that topic? You can find it here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SupportingNotificationsinYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH4-SW10